# search a string from file which contains only specific symbol and number in unix through Grep command

Tags: shell, unix, grep, sh

I want to search a line from file which contains "+", number and character. If any other character available in string then complete string should be discarded.

- A1264
- 13255
- 1255+*
- *6_54
- 54789+

Output should be

- A1264
- 13255
- 54789+

  Record number 3 and 4 should not come as it contains some other character also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
grep -E  '^[a-zA-Z0-9\+]+$'
```

This will accept only a to z chars (small and caps), digits and `+` sign

If you have other symbols you can edit the command line:

```
# grep -E '^[a-fA-F0-9©]+$' a1
A1264
13255
54789©
```

Comment: I have one more doubt how to search some special character like © or » or ¼ or ½.

Comment: @user331814, you can edit the command and use copy/paste to add some additional characters

Comment: I have tried this grep -E  '^[a-fA-F0-9\©]+$' file and when I have pasted it to unix console it looks like grep -E  '^[a-fA-F0-9\\251]+$' file. and its still not working.

Comment: I am not able to search only 1 record with above code. Data :-  "081-54770/13"  code I have used "grep -E '^[0-9\-\/]+$' file".

Comment: @user331814, change the grep like this: `grep -E  '^[0-9/-]+$' `. And if you find the answer useful you can consider to upvote and/or accept the answer

Comment: this code gives only number which contains "-" but it not return string which contains slash "/"

Comment: Here is what I get when run it: `cat a1; grep -E  '^[0-9/-]+$' a1
081-54770/13
081-54770/13
`